# What does '**/*.coffee' mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

What does `**` mean in a regular expression, I'm looking at the following piece of code:

```
def coffee2js
  coffee_folder = self.config['coffeescript_folder'] || '**/*.coffee'
  compile_coffeescript(["*.coffee", coffee_folder], /\.coffee$/, '.js')
end
```

Isn't saying `**/*.coffee` the same as saying `*/*.coffee`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a regex, this is syntax of [globbing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

This expression

```
Dir.glob('/some/dir/**/*.coffee')
```

finds all `.coffee` files under `/some/dir` in all directories recursively (as opposed to looking only at `/some/dir` and not going into nested dirs).